# snowflake delete staging tables pyspark aws glue

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-glue

I have a daily spark glue job that updates (mode:overwrite) a table in Snowflake and each time it runs, it generates a staging table in the format table-name_staging_123947678...

I just need a little assistance to push the last part of my script over the finish line

```
df1.write.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME).options(**sfOptions).option("header", "true").option("dbtable", "table").mode("overwrite").save()

sdf = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME).options(**sfOptions).option("query", """
SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' || table_name || ';' 
FROM  MyDatabase.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%STAGING%';
""").load()

for row in sdf.rdd.collect():
    net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Utils.runQuery((sfOptions, row)
```

My issue comes at the Utils.runQuery at the end... any ideas on the correct script in the for loop to write drop table queries against Snowflake from Glue/spark?

Comment: Are you getting an error when you run above or is it not doing what you expect it to do?

Comment: getting an error based on the last line of code.. tried importing that net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Utils but doesn't recognize and just Utils.runQuery doesn't work so wondering the the code should look like

Comment: I'm not a Spark person by any means, but in the Python world I think we'd need to reference a column of a dataframe.  And to test that theory, I'd probably create a string from row/column, and then use the string in your runQuery() command.  But again, I could be way off here.